# Contact Us form data view from admin

Tags: admin, database, forms, contact-us

A dumb question probably, but does magento save data submited from Contact Us form to database? If yes, is there a way to view it from admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it doesn't. You can take a look at app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controller/IndexController.php (postAction method). Unfortunately i don't see an event that has been dispatched in either the controller or in the Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template. But you still can do it using events like controller_action_predispatch and controller_action_postdispatch. Take a look at http://www.anyknowledge.com/magento-all-about-pre-dispath-and-post-dispatch-dynamic-events/